# How to pass a program's output to another program's stdin?

Tags: process

I have a small C program taking input with scanf()

```
int main(){
    char* buf[10];
    scanf("%s", buf);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to pass scanf another program's output (some python generated string or even an`echo aaa` at first).

I thought about piping the output directly to stdin (from another terminal) doing this :

`pidof a.out
xxx
echo aaa > /proc/xxx/fd/0`

But it only prints `aaa` on my C program's terminal, still waiting for an input.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What if the input is bigger than 10 characters? You should probably use malloc() instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just

```
echo 'string' | ./a.out
```

The shell will see to that the piping is done correctly, and your program will simply read from its standard input.

---

What you're attempting is a highly non-portable *redirection*, not a pipe.

Also, remember to check the return code from `scanf()` and make sure your input buffer is large enough to hold the input. Ideally use a format string that restricts the number of chars read, e.g. `%9s` or something similar in your example.

Comment: Thanks,
Still, how would I do this if I had multiple chained scanf in my program ?

Comment: @user162119 "Chained"?  If you read multiple strings, just pipe multiple strings.